# Get select field options from a custom DB table in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Within the wordpress database I have a table called tab_clients
In this table I have the following columns:
id, name, cpf, cnpj, ie, razao_social, email, phone, mobile, representative (wordpress user id), status, photo, date_since, data_cadastro

I need to bring these values into a select field in the checkout form of woocommerce, but when I declare the variable 'options' => array ($ client-> name), it only brings me a single result.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'cliente_woocommerce' ); 
function cliente_woocommerce( $checkout ) { 
echo '<div id="cliente_woocommerce"><h2>' . __('Cliente') . '</h2>'; 
$clientes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, nome, cnpj FROM tab_clientes" );
foreach($clientes as $cliente);

woocommerce_form_field( 'cliente', array( 
    'type' => 'select', 
    'class' => array('cliente form-row-wide'), 
    'label' => __('Campo de Teste (Cliente)'), 
    'placeholder' => __('Selecione o cliente'), 
    'options'   =>  array($cliente->nome), 
), $checkout->get_value( 'cliente' ) );

echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following revisited code that will give you the correct options array with multiple values for this checkout custom select field:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'cliente_woocommerce' ); 
function cliente_woocommerce( $checkout ) 
{ 
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, nome, cnpj FROM tab_clientes" );
    $otions  = array( '' => __('Selecione o cliente') );

    // Loop through the data query results
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $options[$result->id] = $result->nome;
    }

    echo '<div id="cliente_woocommerce"><h2>' . __('Cliente') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'cliente', array( 
        'type' => 'select', 
        'class' => array('cliente form-row-wide'), 
        'label' => __('Campo de Teste (Cliente)'), 
        'options'   =>  $options, 
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'cliente' ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked!

I do not want to abuse, but, can I create other fields (input) and fill with the other values from the selection?

Comment: @NeiCarreira Yes I suppose… Just try yourself and if you get some trouble, just ask a new question, with the necessary details.

Comment: for now, thank you.
I made a symbolic donation in appreciation of your great help.